# Can I make Flow use an arbitrary Babel plugin (or other code-transforming widget)?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, flowtype

I am using Create React App and Flow.  I can add arbitrary Babel plugins for use in Create React App by specifying them in config-overrides.js (with help from react-app-rewired and customize-cra).  I can add Babel plugins for use in my Jest tests by naming them in babel.config.js.  In these ways I can transform code before these tools have a chance to be confused by whatever nonstandard syntax I want to use (JavaScript decorators, for instance).

But I don't know how to do the same for Flow.  It doesn't seem to accept Babel plugins.  Maybe it parses code completely on its own and doesn't even use Babel?  I don't know.  Does Flow itself take plugins?  I don't know.

Is there some simple way for me to plug a function into SOME tool or other in order to arbitrarily transform my code just before Flow sees it?  Or would I actually have to dig into Flow's source code and alter it in order to accomplish this?  (I am not interested enough to do that.)

Comment: Why do you need to transform the code for Flow? Are you getting an error? If so, it would be helpful to post the code/error you're seeing.

Comment: I'd rather not go into that.  If I'm asking the wrong question then I still would like to know the answer to it!

Comment: Flow cannot run Babel plugins. If you're using experimental syntax via Babel then it needs to be syntax that Flow itself also knows how to handle, so without knowing what error you're getting or what syntax is causing the issue, there's no useful way to answer this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Flow] doesn't seem to accept Babel plugins.

No, flow has support for some proposed ECMAScript features (some of which were previously behind flow config options), but it does not have any kind of plugin system.

> Maybe it parses code completely on its own and doesn't even use Babel?

It does. Flow implements a [fully-fledged JavaScript -> AST parser](https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/master/src/parser#the-flow-parser) that can be used entirely independently of the flow type checker.

> Does Flow itself take plugins? I don't know.

No. I think that [this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1515#issuecomment-194601192) is the most relevant issue suggesting this possibility:

> one example I could imagine is if you wanted to put some Babel transforms in front of flow, to transpile experimental/custom language features back to ES6 without having to write it to a JS file and then reparse it again.

In this case he's saying that if flow could take any arbitrary compatible AST as input and perform type checking on it, then babel transforms could be performed on that AST *before* it was fed into flow.

> Is there some simple way for me to plug a function into SOME tool or other in order to arbitrarily transform my code just before Flow sees it? Or would I actually have to dig into Flow's source code and alter it in order to accomplish this? (I am not interested enough to do that.)

The answer is hinted at above. The tool you describe would generally be babel. Basically you could run babel transforms over your code to remove constructions that flow does not recognize, then check the resulting intermediary JavaScript files using flow. By its nature, this solution precludes the possibility of something like LSP or other real-time checking, as you would always be performing a full check as part of a two-step process.

At the end of the day, there are very few situations in which such an approach would be worthwhile. The case would need to be highly non-standard.